# How do I change the Start and End marker image in Google Maps v3 API for Directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

I have a route plotted fine on using DirectionsRender but I cannot find out how to replace the generic Google markers with my own.

I know and use this in a normal Google Map situation but finding it difficult to do this with the directions markers for start and end.

Thanks for any advice, pointers or gentle mocking if this is a silly question :D

Michael

Answer (score 8):

The [`DirectionRender`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRendererOptions) takes an option called [`markerOptions`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions). Quoting from the API docs:

> All markers rendered by the DirectionsRenderer will use these options.

So, if you want to set the markers use [MarkerImage](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage) (as philar has indicated).

Your other option is to pass `suppressMarkers: true` to the `DirectionRender`'s options and then simply use your own markers.

Answer (score 4):

this is how you need to approach it

**Declare all your image icons as shown below**

```
var movingIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/img/icon_moving.jpg');
var startIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/img/icon_start.png');
```

**Then while creating the marker, use the icon option to set the specific image to that marker**

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: map,
            icon: movingIcon
            });
```

Comment: He was asking how to change the markers in the directions rendering this just answers how to change the marker icon.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to add this on your `DirectionsRenderer`

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true}); 
//to hide the default icons
```

then after options etc...

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
//you set your custom image
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/image.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(129, 42),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(18, 42)
                );

//you set your icon for each of the direction points Origin
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(19.432651,-99.133201),
                    map: map,
                    icon: image
                });
//you set your icon for each of the direction points Destination,
                var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.508648,-73.55399),
                    map: map,
                    icon: image
                });
```

you can also add different icons for origin and destination. Just play with the var image, 
it works for me!