# Change individual markers in google maps directions api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking to change the marker icons when using the DirectionsRender within a google map. I've figured out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312961/how-do-i-change-the-start-and-end-marker-image-in-google-maps-v3-api-for-directio) how to change both the markers to the same icon, but I am looking for custom icons on both the start and end points. Any ideas?

Edit: I'm looking for how to assign separate icons to the start and end markers. I know how to change it for both, but having different marker icons is proving difficult.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

For those that need an example like I did, here's a basic one:

```
 // Map and directions objects
 var map = new google.maps.Map( element, options );
 var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 var directions = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});

 // Start/Finish icons
 var icons = {
  start: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
   // URL
   'start.png',
   // (width,height)
   new google.maps.Size( 44, 32 ),
   // The origin point (x,y)
   new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
   // The anchor point (x,y)
   new google.maps.Point( 22, 32 )
  ),
  end: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
   // URL
   'end.png',
   // (width,height)
   new google.maps.Size( 44, 32 ),
   // The origin point (x,y)
   new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
   // The anchor point (x,y)
   new google.maps.Point( 22, 32 )
  )
 };

service.route( { origin: origin, destination: destination }, function( response, status ) {
 if ( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ) {
  display.setDirections( response );
  var leg = response.routes[ 0 ].legs[ 0 ];
  makeMarker( leg.start_location, icons.start, "title" );
  makeMarker( leg.end_location, icons.end, 'title' );
 }
});
function makeMarker( position, icon, title ) {
 new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map: map,
  icon: icon,
  title: title
 });
}
```

The response from a route request returns a leg(s) depending on the number of stops on your route. I am only doing a A to B route, so just take the first leg, and get the position of where the markers need to go, and create markers for those spots.

Comment: What about changing the markers within the directions themselves?

Comment: I added functionallity to clear all markers before calculating directions for a 2nd time. Also see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Comment: how can i hide the old marker ? cause the new markers is succssefuly added, but the A and B marker showd also :((

Comment: @OumayaAbdelkhalek Look at the `directions` variable. `{suppressMarkers: true}` turns off the default markers.

Comment: Changing the markers in the directions panel was actually easier than expected (especially with jQuery).  The image has the class `adp-marker`, so you can just set that element's src attribute to the same url as your marker's icon.

If you want custom info windows, use `suppresInfoWindows: true`. Look up `adp-placemark` elements and change the click event for **its parent** to open your own info window.

Comment: Can you make a JS Fiddle for this implementation actually i tried this code but i was unable to add label to the marker

Comment: Why not pass map to makeMarker?

Comment: The markers are not lining up perfectly with the ends of the polyline like the default markers, is it better to not suppress the default markers and instead change the markerOptions in the Directions Renderer options?

Comment: I have used the above code but in my case only show polyline not start and end icon are not show.in above code line :display.setDirections( response ); why use display var here?

Comment: I have a similar problem removing the default markers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76408261/how-to-display-multiple-source-and-destination-on-a-single-map-with-custom-pin-i

Answer (score 12):

Do as they say on that page you linked to:

- Set the [suppressMarkers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRendererOptions) option to true to prevent the default start and end markers from showing
- Create the [images](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage) for the two new markers
- Create the [markers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) with the position set to the start and end positions, and the icon set to the ones you created

Comment: But how do you assign them to the Renderer object? It only takes one MarkerOptions object, not two.

Comment: you don't assign them. just get the coordinates for them and create two new markers.