# Plotting two routes at same time with google maps api

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to plot two routes at same time with Google maps api.
For Example

```
Route from city A to B
and Route from city C to D
```

In this case A,B and C,D are separated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two polylines on the same map; there doesn't appear to be a limit.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcde/3/

I didn't add the div panels (becomes too cluttered) but you can also show two sets of text directions. It's a bit confusing because both start points are shown as "A" and endpoints, "B". Add the following lines:

```
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("dir-1"));
directionsDisplay2.setPanel(document.getElementById("dir-2"));

<div id="dir-1"></div>
<div id="dir-2"></div>
```

Comment: You can change the displayed markers by suppressing the default ones, getting the start/finish coordinates from the results and creating your own markers to put at those locations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813728/change-individual-markers-in-google-maps-directions-api-v3

Comment: That's worth mentioning Andrew! I meant the markers that show up in the (text) directions panels; those I have no idea how to modify.